WordPress: How can I make a submenu block the content below it?
How can I set my dropdown menu so that it covers whatever content is below it and I can still click the links? I'm creating a page with several menus stacked on top of each other, but when the dropdown of a higher up one has more than ~2 sub items, they overlap the menu below and I can't click the lower sub items. Here's a screenshot of my work in progress:

When I hover over "San Francisco" it closes the top menu and opens up the lower one.
CSS code would be great or anything else that will work. Thanks

If I've understood this you're asking how to allow your user to click something that they can't see? That sounds like a bad idea. If I click on something that says 'San Francisco' I expect to go to a page that relates to SanFran. It seems that you want to click something unseen beneath, which might be 'Oregon', or 'Windsurfing'

In broad terms you can adjust the z-index to determine which elements are in front of other elements. If you need more specific help you will need to edit your post to include a runnable example or at least the relevant parts of your code.

replying to @TangentiallyPerpendicular No, that's not the issue. You can still interact with the beneath menus, in your example that might say "Oregon," but the user can't click "San Francisco" because when they hover over it, the submenu goes away and the one below (e.g. Oregon) opens up.

@BrettDonald z-indexing worked! Might get a little tedious but does the job. Thanks!
